# How to use SSRS parameter as multiselect as well as manual input type?

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, cube

I have an SSRS report which uses a cube. Report having cascading parameter ID and Name. The ID parameter having values `No Value, 111, 222`. If the user selects `111` then the Name parameter is populated with names under `111` and the same for `222`. If the user selects the `No value` in the ID parameter then the Name parameter should allow the user to type value manually in it.

I want the Name parameter to work as multi-select and as the input type. Is that possible in the SSRS report?

Comment: Multidimensional or Tabular SSAS?

Comment: I would like to know that but really the question is whether your SSRS dataset is using a MDX query or a DAX/DMX query?